# Solr 6.1 warning: Couldn't add files to classpath

Tags: solr, solr6, solrconfig

I freshly configured a Solr 6.1 server (actually a migration from version 4) and get a lot of warnings like:

```
WARN  (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-2) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrConfig Couldn't add files from C:\dev\solr-6.1.0\server\solr\configsets\foobar\..\..\..\dist filtered by solr-cell-\d.*\.jar to classpath: C:\dev\solr-6.1.0\server\solr\configsets\foobar\..\..\..\dist
```

or

```
WARN  (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-2) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrConfig Couldn't add files from C:\dev\solr-6.1.0\server\solr\configsets\foobar\..\..\..\contrib\extraction\lib filtered by .*\.jar to classpath: C:\dev\solr-6.1.0\server\solr\configsets\foobar\..\..\..\contrib\extraction\lib
```

But: There are no *.jar files anywhere below `C:\dev\solr-6.1.0\server\solr\configsets\foobar` (in fact there is only a subdirectory `conf` with some `.xml` files) and the server is running fine so far, so I'm wondering what this warning is going to tell me. Can I just ignore it? Am I missing anything important?

Comment: What do you have in solrconfig.xml ? seems to be path is wrong for a libary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Oyeme's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38694146/solr-6-1-warning-couldnt-add-files-to-classpath/38694907#comment64768062_38694146) I discovered that I included some [example stuff](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Lib+Directives+in+SolrConfig) in the solrconfig.xmls:

```
<lib dir="../../../contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar"/>
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar"/>

<lib dir="../../../contrib/clustering/lib/" regex=".*\.jar"/>
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-clustering-\d.*\.jar"/>

<lib dir="../../../contrib/langid/lib/" regex=".*\.jar"/>
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-langid-\d.*\.jar"/>

<lib dir="../../../contrib/velocity/lib" regex=".*\.jar"/>
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-velocity-\d.*\.jar"/>
```

Deleting these lines was the solution.